# Find all INTs BETWEEN multiple ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm dealing with document parent/child families in a discovery tool.

Is there an easy way to return all numbers between a list of multiple ranges?

I have a `#tempTable` with 359 rows containing a `StartingBatesNumber`, `BegAtt`, and `EndAtt`

The `BegAtt` is the beginning of a Bates range, and the `EndAtt` is the last document in the bates range.  here's some sample data from the `#tempTable`:

```
StartingBatesNumber BegAtt  EndAtt
CTRL00262209    CTRL00262208    CTRL00262209
CTRL00262295    CTRL00262292    CTRL00262295
CTRL00262325    CTRL00262323    CTRL00262326
CTRL00262348    CTRL00262347    CTRL00262362
CTRL00262398    CTRL00262395    CTRL00262399
CTRL00262518    CTRL00262509    CTRL00262597
CTRL00262575    CTRL00262509    CTRL00262597
CTRL00262946    CTRL00262934    CTRL00262955
CTRL00263301    CTRL00263280    CTRL00263304
CTRL00263342    CTRL00263336    CTRL00263360
CTRL00263602    CTRL00263590    CTRL00263614
CTRL00263649    CTRL00263648    CTRL00263649
CTRL00263810    CTRL00263809    CTRL00263810
CTRL00264691    CTRL00264690    CTRL00264691
CTRL00265211    CTRL00265192    CTRL00265320
```

This temp table is a subset of a larger table called `ExportedItems` that contains the same columns.  I need to select every `StartingBatesNumber` that is between any of the `BegAtt` AND `EndAtt` from the items on the `#tempTable`.  What I have so far is:

```
SELECT EI.StartingBatesNumber
FROM ExportedItems AS EI WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE EI.StartingBatesNumber BETWEEN #tempTable.BegAtt AND #tempTable.EndAtt
ORDER BY EI.StartingBatesNumber
```

I understand I cannot join my #tempTable like that, but If i added a formal join on `StartingBatesNumber` then my results would be restricted to only the items on the subset and not allow me to pull in the StartingBatesNumbers that weren't on my list already.  I would like to find a recursive way to select all StartingBatesNumbers between all the ranges on my #tempTable.

I know I can solve this using a cursor to increment through the loop, but I was wondering if there was an easier way.  Maybe a recursive CTE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand I cannot join my #tempTable like that

I'm not sure what you mean.  This is perfectly valid as a SQL statement:

```
SELECT EI.StartingBatesNumber
FROM ExportedItems EI WITH (NOLOCK) JOIN
     #tempTable tt
     ON EI.StartingBatesNumber BETWEEN tt.BegAtt AND tt.EndAtt
ORDER BY EI.StartingBatesNumber;
```

Your statement is not correct, because you refer to a table that is not defined in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Wow, that does it perfectly!  I guess I was just stuck in the mindset that a JOIN needs to be equal to a PK or FK and didn't realize I could join on a range.  Thanks a bundle!  I've been scratching my head over this for a while.  I guess I was pretty close lol.